# Capture full-range/lossless rgb frame from capture card that supports NV12 and YUYV output

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, colors, rgb, nv12-nv21

I am trying to make a program which captures an image, then i need to compare captured image and the input data which i displayed, both should matc pixel by pixel

Here are the details of my capture card

$ v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext -d /dev/video0

```
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Type: Video Capture

        [0]: 'NV12' (Y/CbCr 4:2:0)
                Size: Discrete 3840x2160
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 2560x1440
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1920x1080
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1280x720
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
        [1]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
                Size: Discrete 2560x1440
                        Interval: Discrete 0.020s (50.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1920x1080
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1280x720
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.017s (60.000 fps)
        [2]: '' (30313050-0000-0010-8000-00aa003)
        [3]: '' (e436eb7e-524f-11ce-9f53-0020af0)
```

$ v4l2-ctl --all

```
Driver Info:
        Driver name      : uvcvideo
        Card type        : ITE HDMI 4K+ Bridge: ITE HDMI 4
        Bus info         : usb-0000:00:14.0-6
        Driver version   : 5.18.0
        Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
                Video Capture
                Metadata Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps      : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 1920/1080
        Pixel Format      : 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
        Field             : None
        Bytes per Line    : 3840
        Size Image        : 4147200
        Colorspace        : sRGB
        Transfer Function : Rec. 709
        YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Rec. 709
        Quantization      : Default (maps to Limited Range)
        Flags             :
Crop Capability Video Capture:
        Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1920, Height 1080
        Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 1920, Height 1080
        Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection Video Capture: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1920, Height 1080, Flags:
Selection Video Capture: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 1920, Height 1080, Flags:
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
        Capabilities     : timeperframe
        Frames per second: 60.000 (60/1)
        Read buffers     : 0
```

I have tried using various methods opencv but ffmpeg came the closest

With below command i am able to get good results but not what i want

```
ffmpeg -y -f v4l2 -pix_fmt NV12 -video_size 1920x1080 -i /dev/video0 -pix_fmt bgra -frames:v 10 webcam%03d.bmp
```

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvkjH.png)

[RGB of Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7lOZ.png)

[RGB of captured image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZwZc.png)

Note :- I am able to capture fine with Aforge on windows, but not with ffmpeg on linux.
Would like to know if anyone has already got solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to mark the input as [BT.709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709) with "TV Range":

`ffmpeg -y -f v4l2 -pix_fmt nv12 -video_size 1920x1080 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 -color_range tv -i /dev/video0 -pix_fmt bgra -frames:v 10 webcam%03d.bmp`

---

Marking the input color format as BT.709:

By default FFmpeg assumes [BT.601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._601) color format, and the input video applies BT.709 color format, so we have to mark the video as BT.709 using `-color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709` arguments.

When the input color format is BT.709, and FFmpeg convert it as it were BT.601, the result is wrong output colors.

---

Marking the range as "TV Range":
By default FFmpeg assumes assumes "Limited Range" (TV range), but we may add `-color_range tv` to be sure.

Note:
"TV Range" applies "Limited range" - the range of Y color channel is [16, 235] (U and V rane is [16, 240]).
(opposed to "Full range" or "PC Range" where YUV range is [0, 255]).

---

For reproducing the issue, we may use synthetic video (instead of camera).

Create a reference image:
`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt bgra ref%03d.bmp`

Create NV12 raw frame in BT.709, "Limited Range" (TV Range):
`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=1:duration=1 -vf scale=out_color_matrix=bt709:out_range=tv -pix_fmt nv12 -f rawvideo in.nv12`

Convert the raw frame to BMP without marking the color format and range (getting wrong colors):
`ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pix_fmt nv12 -video_size 192x108 -i in.nv12 -pix_fmt bgra -frames:v 1 wrong_colors_out%03d.bmp`

Convert the raw frame to BMP with marking the color format and range (getting correct colors):
`ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pix_fmt nv12 -video_size 192x108 -color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 -color_range tv -i in.nv12 -pix_fmt bgra -frames:v 1 out%03d.bmp`

---

Ordered left to right:
Reference image, "wrong colors" and "correct colors":
[image] [image]  [image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the explanation. This totally works now getting correct pixel values.